# implementar sharedPreferences en java android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Después de estar 5 horas intentando implementar sharePreferents me siento frustrado , no entiendo ningún ejemplo de los que estuve revisando para aplicarlo a mi proyecto:

La idea es no perder la información de la cuenta regresiva que se hace al hacer clic en binding.spinweel . Intente guardar un timestamp en firebase y recuperarlo pero no fui capaz y elegí hacerlo con sharepreferences pero sin ningún resultado positivo.

si pudierais ayudarme un poco lo agradecería muchísimo, el código donde pretendo implementarlo es un Fragment que dejo a continuación :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {



public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


FragmentHomeBinding binding;
FirebaseFirestore database;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    


    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

    database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    final ArrayList<CategoryModel> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    final CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), categories);

    database.collection("categories")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                    categories.clear();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot: value.getDocuments()) {
                        CategoryModel model = snapshot.toObject(CategoryModel.class);
                        model.setCategoryId(snapshot.getId());
                        categories.add(model);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });


    binding.categoryList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),1));
    binding.categoryList.setAdapter(adapter);


    binding.spinwheel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), SpinnerActivity.class));
            // hacer visible el spinweelTime
            binding.spinwheelTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new CountDownTimer(3000000,1000){
                @Override
                final public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


                    int second = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60 ;
                    int minute = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60)) % 60);
                    int hour   = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

                    binding.spinwheelTime.setText(""+hour+":"+minute+":"+second );
                    binding.spinwheelTime.setEnabled(false);
                    binding.spinwheel.setEnabled(false);



                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // hacer invisible el boton para que se muestre el btnspinweel
                    binding.spinwheelTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    binding.spinwheel.setEnabled(true);

                }


        }.start();


            };

    });////






    binding.sharewhatBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            waIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String text = "Mira esta aplicación https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.messenger";

            waIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);// mejorar como por ejemplo poner el enlace a la appstore
            waIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Compartir con"));

            waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

Comment: Hola, no explicas donde o como deseas usar SharedPreferences? cual es el valor que tratas de guardar? como lo intentaste?, te sugerimos revisar [ask] y explicar tu problema, ser más especifico , saludos.

Comment: hola, gracias por la respuesta. Mi intencion es que al pulsar el boton "binding.spinwheel" y se active ".setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {....." se mantenga la cuenta atras aun cuando el usuario salga de la aplicacion o la elimine de correr en segundo plano. No se muy bien si la forma correcta es usando sharedPrefences o usando un servicio o quizas con otra forma que desconozca actualmente, estuve realizando pruebas con un servicio y funciona pero cuando eliminas de correr en segundo plano la app tambien se pierde la cuenta. Creo que crear un servicio tampoco es la solucion

Comment: No se que tipo de solución se suele utilizar para lo que pretendo hacer , la idea es que si se pulsar ese botón ahora hasta dentro de 8 horas no se pueda volver a pulsar. Quizás guardando un valor en la base de datos de firebase ? no se necesito saber como se suele enfocar esto dado que soy nuevo y no se si como estoy planteando el problema realmente es una solución para lo que pretendo hacer

Comment: si entiendo a través de eso como usar las sharepreferences pero me doy cuenta que no es la solución para guardar una cuenta atrás que funcione aunque el usuario cierre la aplicación. Como podría resolver el problema ? Lo intente implementando un servicio pero cuando el usuario cierra la app se pierde también la información